# How to apply Angular-Universal in Multi-project/Workspace?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, multi-project

I Need to Install angular-universal in my Workspace/Multi-Project Application.But the worst case is that I can't able to find any Document/video reference in angular.io(Official Website).They are demonstrated for only single project.

Need Step by step guide or any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There  is not much documentation but [this blog](https://medium.com/@philip_lysenko/angular-universal-with-nrwl-nx-ca2996a7da2) gave me a hint.

You can add Angular-Universal to a specific project in your workspace with the below command.

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject yourProjectName
```

Answer (score 1):

For new angular version:
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --project projectName

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Consider adding a short explanation